# Worklight WAS Liberty profile configuration based on Tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, active-directory, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

For a Pilot project we've set up a Worklight server on a WAS using the Liberty profile. We're basing it on the configuration LDAP configuration of a Tomcat server (used for RTC) on the same machine, but they don't seem to map propertly to each other (in the sense that we can't just "copy-paste" the configuration. We've come to the point where logging into the LDAP server (An Active Directory server) works, but the login doesn't work and doesn't return any error message apart from a failed login in the logs. I am rather sure the binding to the LDAP server succeeds, since when changing the password in the configuration to any other value to the correct one, the log shows a problem regarding it.

Is it possible to take a look at these configurations and see what could be wrong?

The configurations are the following:

For the Tomcat server:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm" 
connectionName="OurCompanyName\JAZZ" connectionPassword="password" 
connectionURL="ldap://servername:389" debug="99" 
referrals="follow" 
roleBase="OU=Security Groups,OU=MyBusiness,DC=OurCompanyName,DC=local" 
roleName="cn" roleSearch="(member={0})" roleSubtree="true"  
userBase="OU=SBSUsers,OU=Users,OU=MyBusiness,DC=OurCompanyName,DC=local" 
userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})" 
userSubtree="true">
```

For the WAS Liberty profile:

```
<ldapRegistry 
ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory"
bindDN="OurCompanyName\JAZZ"
bindPassword="password" 
baseDN="OU=Security Groups,OU=MyBusiness,DC=OurCompanyName,DC=local"
host="servername" 
id="ActiveDirectoryLDAP"
port="389" 
ignoreCase="true" 
userFilter="&amp;(sAMAccountname={0})"
groupFilter="&amp;(member={0})"     
referral="follow"
roleSubtree="true"
userSubtree="true"
userIdMap="*:uid"
groupIdMap="*:cn"
debug="99"> 
</ldapRegistry>
```

Thanks,

Kristof

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of your Liberty Profile ?

The full support of referrals in Liberty is only in 8.5.5.1 (or 8.5.5.0 with an iFix) and the property name is referal not referral (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM96984)

You must define also an attribute loginProperty="uid" (not yet documented). Also roleSubtree, userSubree, debug seem not supported.

Comment: Hi there Bruno, we updated our Liberty Profile to 8.5.5.1, the login doesn't work yet though. Any idea whether there's an alternative for roleSubtree and userSubtree?