# Configuring WAS Liberty LDAP authentication settings based on Tomcat configuration

Tags: tomcat, ldap, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

I have a similar question as this:

[Worklight WAS Liberty profile configuration based on Tomcat configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677216/worklight-was-liberty-profile-configuration-based-on-tomcat-configuration)

@Kristof: Did you figure out how to do it?

I'm using openldap. So my ldapType is Custom. So my configuration is:

```
<ldapRegistry 
    baseDN="ou=people,dc=my-domain,dc=com" 
    ldapType="Custom"
    port="389" 
    host="MyServerHost" 
    id="myLdap"
    bindDN="" 
    bindPassword=""
    searchTimeout="300000m" 
    recursiveSearch="true">
    <customFilters
        id="customFilters"
        userFilter="(uid={0})"
        userIdMap="*:uid"
        groupFilter="(member={0})"
        groupIdMap="*:cn"/>         
</ldapRegistry>
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried using something like

```
<customFilters
    id="customFilters"
    userFilter="(&amp;(uid=%v)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))"
    groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(|(objectclass=organizationalUnit)))"
    groupMemberIdMap="posixGroup:memberUid"/>
```

But that doesn't fix it either. The question is what does that all represent anyway? I have no clue what objectClass is... or where the value inetOrgPerson needs to come from. Moreover, there's no way to represent roleBase in the liberty configuration. I set baseDN to the userBase value.

Why do we need the properties like userIdMap and groupIdMap?

After reading a lot more, I updated the configuration to:

```
<ldapRegistry 
    baseDN="dc=my-domain,dc=com" 
    ldapType="Custom"
    port="389" 
    host="myLdapServerHost" 
    id="myLdap"
    bindDN="cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com" 
    bindPassword="admin"
    recursiveSearch="true">
    <customFilters
        id="customFilters"
        userFilter="&amp;(ou=people)(uid=%v)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)"
        groupFilter="&amp;(ou=groupsJ2EE)(cn=%v)(objectClass=groupOfNames)"/>
</ldapRegistry>
```

Still no luck.... any ideas of what could be wrong?

Comment: I'm using openldap so the configuration will be slightly different. And the other question doesn't have an answer either.

Comment: sorry about that. i updated the question. my question is similar, but not exactly teh same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filters need to be as below.

```
<customFilters
    id="customFilters"
    userFilter="&amp;(uid=%v)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)"
    groupFilter="&amp;(cn=%v)(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
    userIdMap="*:uid"
    groupMemberIdMap="groupOfNames:member"/>/>
```

That is assuming that the OpenLdap is configured to use the inetorgperson.schema (an extension schema provided as part of the standard openldap) by adding the line below in slapd.conf

```
include /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
```

By default OpenLdap does not enable the inetorgperson.schema and in that case the userFilter will need to be something like

```
&amp;(cn=%v)(objectClass=person)
```

and userIdMap will be

```
 "*:cn"
```

Below is a sample ldif file from Open Ldap and a ldap configuration snippet

### Ldif

```
dn: o=ibm,c=in
objectClass: organization
o: ibm

dn: ou=people,o=ibm,c=in
objectClass: organizationalUnit
description: All people in organisation
ou: people

dn: cn=Robert Smith,ou=people,o=ibm,c=in
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Robert Smith
cn: Robert J Smith
cn: bob  smith
sn: smith
uid: rjsmith
userPassword:: e1NIQX1XNnBoNU1tNVB6OEdnaVVMYlBnekczN21qOWc9

dn: uid=testUser,ou=people,o=ibm,c=in
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: top
cn: testUserCN
sn: testUserSN
uid: testUser

dn: ou=groups,o=ibm,c=in
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: groups

dn: cn=testGroup1,ou=groups,o=ibm,c=in
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
cn: testGroup1
member: uid=TESTUSER,ou=PEOPLE,o=IBM,c=IN
```

### Config

```
<ldapRegistry 
    baseDN="o=ibm,c=in" 
    ldapType="Custom"
    port="389" 
    host="9.113.58.110" 
    id="myLdap"
    bindDN="cn=root,o=ibm,c=in" 
    bindPassword="root"
    recursiveSearch="true">
    <customFilters
        id="customFilters"
        userFilter="&amp;(uid=%v)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)"
        groupFilter="&amp;(cn=%v)(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
        userIdMap="*:uid"
        groupMemberIdMap="groupOfNames:member"/>/>
</ldapRegistry>
```

Comment: The following worked for me:

     <ldapRegistry 
  baseDN="dc=my-domain,dc=com" 
  ldapType="Custom"
  port="389" 
  host="MyServerHost" 
  id="OpenLDAP"
  bindDN="cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com" 
  bindPassword="admin"
  recursiveSearch="true"
  realm="ldapRealm">
  <customFilters
   userFilter="(&amp;(uid=%v)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))"
   groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectClass=groupOfNames))"/>
 </ldapRegistry>

Comment: Hello, can you please confirm baseDN="o=ibm,c=in" ? If I do that I won't be able to authenticate. I need to do baseDN="ou=people,o=ibm,c=in". Then auth works but user gets not groups/roles assigned and can't access protected resources. Any ideas what I'm missing? (I included the recursiveSearch="true" in ldapRegistri, of course). Thanks.